# Memory problems with meteor app on nitrous.io

Tags: mongodb, meteor, nitrous

I have a meteor project on a nitrous box ( 512 mb ).
i suddenly started to have problems when starting the application. the mongodb can't start.
I made a `meteor reset` to reset the database but still have the same problems
Nothing changed on my project and i dont know why i have "not enough memory" .

I even updated my box to 640 mb but i still have the same problem.

Comment: Did you try to add cordova? That filled up a 512mb nitrous box for me.

Comment: I have only the default platforms : browser and server

Answer (score 1):

This is a something very usual on Nitrous.io

Since MongoDB stores Prealloc Version of the DB, you should need to remove them (delete) from the project.

Also take a look on the auto pars, if you are not using Heroku remove it.

take a look on this route.

```
root>projectName>.meteor>local>db>journal
```

And remove the Preallocs (this is not a good practice, but seems to be only solution on a Free nitrous.io box)

Good luck